# Spring MVC Portlet reuse in Websphere Portal

Tags: java, code-reuse, websphere-portal, spring-portlet-mvc

I have application in which there are several portlets created, simple java mvc portlet.
Is it possible to reuse the portlet in another application, without duplicating code? 
What are the implications and what changes should be done?

Thank you.

Comment: It is possible, but exactly how you probably need to describe a bit more of how you want it in another application. You could have multiple instances of the same portlet in the portal for example. It depends a bit on your requirements.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but right now I'm just looking into ways of how to do this. Right now I'm curios to see if it's possible to reuse a portlet that exists on a different server in a different application/page. I've seen some option to export a portlet, but I don't know the implications and how maintainable such an option would be.

Comment: Absolutely. A portlet can be redeployed in as many environments as you like. That depends only on the portlet itself. Likewise you can both clone the portlet within an environment to be able to have multiple configurations as well as have multiple instances of the same portlet (deploy the same portlet on multiple pages).

Comment: Understanding your question a bit better, I have made an answer from my comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a portlet it can be deployed in many different ways. You can deploy the same portlet without code changes into multiple environments.

Once the portlet is deployed in an environment you can also:

- Clone it, ie make a copy of it, which will allow you to change the portlet configuration without making two separate portlets.
- Use the same portlet on different pages (multiple instances).

All of the above without doing any changes to the actual portlet. Now, keep in mind that it also all depends on the portlet. If the developers of the portlet have included many hard coded parameters, this may not be possible to do. I recommend that you keep the server/environment dependent parts in configurations rather than hard coded.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I agree with your answer and I will try to make it work to see which is my best way of doing things.